# Psycopg2 Install Issue (Mac)

Tags: python, postgresql, pip, homebrew, psycopg2

I've been trying to install psycopg2. I have Postgres App and PostgreSQL installed, have gone through all the Stack Overflow answers on other cases but I seem to still have trouble installing. I'm running Mac OSX and Python 3.8.5.

Firstly when I do `import psycopg2` or `import psycopg`, I get this project error `No module named 'psycopg2'` or `No module named 'psycopg'`

I've already done all the measures proposed in the documentation, including

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

Perhaps there is an issue with where the pg_config file is being specified and while I know where it is located I don't know how to get postgres to point to it.

Please let me know if there's any further information I can provide that may help get to an answer, and thank you for helping me out with this problem.

Alternatively, if you recommend any other (and less frustrating) Postgres adapters for Python.

Best,
Max

Comment: First `apt` is the package manager for '*.deb` packages and I doubt that will be available on a Mac. Second where there any error messages when you did: `pip install psycopg2-binary`? Third, how was Python installed on your machine?

Comment: Yes, you're right about the apt package manager, as I have come to realize it is not part of pip or homebrew or anaconda, all three which I have installed to see if the package manager was the issue. I did not get any error messages when installing the binary and the psycopg2 package, but neither seem to work. I installed Python so long ago I can't exactly tell you, though I probably downloaded through the python.org website.

Comment: Well you are going to have to determine what your setup is. My suspicion is that you are installing `psycopg2` into one environment and trying to `import` it in another.

Comment: I've been using Pipenv for my local environment, and testing against VirtualEnv to see what's wrong with my dependencies for this situation. Anything else I can detail?

Comment: Honestly I had nothing but problems with `pipenv` and I stay away from it. In the `virtualenv` you are working in do `pip freeze` and see what is actually installed there.

Comment: I ended up opting for virtualenv, PyMySQL, and then installing dependencies locally in the project through PyCharm's terminal. Thank you for your help @AdrianKlaver

Comment: Not sure how  `PyMySQL` is going to help you with Postgres.

Comment: I opted to use MySQL instead as the service was also available on the AWS rds server. Less enthusiastic about it but it gets the same job done.